# Async function with multiple fetch in an array - Best way to do that?

Tags: javascript, arrays, asynchronous, fetch

I'm learning JavaScript and async functions is not my strength.

I have an array of gameIds, and I have to fetch each individual id and get the data of all that games.

```
async function gameInfo() {
    gamesIds = [19,12,13,15,16];

    //what should be here?

    const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:8080/game/${individualGameId}`, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        withCredentials: true,
        credentials: 'include',
        "authorization": "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5c"
      },
    });

    const allGamesInfo = await response.json();
    console.log(allGamesInfo);
}
```

Can someone help me with this ?

Answer (score 3):

The best idea for your problem is creating a Array of Promises and execute it with Promise.all

```js
gamesIds = [19,12,13,15,16];

    const promises = gamesIds.map(id =>                 
      fetch(`http://localhost:8080/game/${id}`, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          withCredentials: true,
          credentials: 'include',
          "authorization": "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5c"
        },
    }))

    const response = await Promise.all(promises);
```